# R splitting a column of character separated by different number of spaces

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame with a column consisting of words separated by a varying number of spaces for example:

```
head(lst)
'fff fffd ddd'
'sss dd'
'de dd'
'dds sssd eew rrr'
'dsds eed'
```

What I would like to have is 2 columns:
The first column is the part before the first space
And the second column is the part after the last space
meaning it should like  this

```
V1       v2
'fff'   'ddd'
'sss'   'dd'
'de'    'dd'
'dds'   'rrr
'dsds'  'eed'
```

The first column I am able to get but the second one is a problem
This is the code I use.

```
  lst <- strsplit(athletes.df$V1, "\\s+")
  v1 <- sapply(lst ,`[`, 1)
  v2 <- sapply(lst, `[`, 2)
```

What I get I get for column v2 is the second word. I know it's because I put 2 inside the sapply How do I tell it to only take what comes after the last space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tail` to grab the last entry of each vector:

```
lst <- strsplit(athletes.df$V1, "\\s+")
v1 <- sapply(lst, head, 1) # example with head to grab first vector element
v2 <- sapply(lst, tail, 1) # example with tail to grab last vector element
```

Or perhaps the `vapply` version since you know your return type should be a character vector:

```
v2 <- vapply(lst, tail, 1, FUN.VALUE = character(1))
```

---

Another approach would be to modify your `strsplit` split criteria to something like this where you split on a space that can optionally be followed by any character one or more times until a final space is found.

```
strsplit(df$V1, "\\s(?:.+\\s)?")
#[[1]]
#[1] "fff" "ddd"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "sss" "dd" 
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "de" "dd"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "dds" "rrr"
#
#[[5]]
#[1] "dsds" "eed"
```

As Sumedh points out this regex works nicely with `tidyr`'s `separate`:

```
tidyr::separate(df, V1, c("V1", "V2"), "\\s(?:.+\\s)?")
#    V1  V2
#1  fff ddd
#2  sss  dd
#3   de  dd
#4  dds rrr
#5 dsds eed
```

---

---

Two `stringi` based approaches:

```
library(stringi)
v1 <- stri_extract_last_regex(df$V1, "\\S+")
v2 <- stri_extract_first_regex(df$V1, "\\S+")
```

Or

```
stri_extract_all_regex(df$V1, "^\\S+|\\S+$", simplify = TRUE)
# this variant explicitly checks for the spaces with lookarounds:
stri_extract_all_regex(df$V1, "^\\S+(?=\\s)|(?<=\\s)\\S+$", simplify = TRUE)
```

Comment: the regex is awesome! Maybe you can add `tidyr::separate(df, V1, c("V1", "V2"), "\\s(?:.+\\s)?")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
lst <- strsplit(athletes.df$V1, "\\s+")
v1 <- sapply(lst ,`[`, 1)
v2 <- sapply(lst, function(x) x[length(x)])
```

Or

```
data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(athletes.df$V1, "\\s+"), 
                    function(x) c(x[1], x[length(x)]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any packages, this can be done with  `read.table` after creating a delimiter using `sub`.

```
read.table(text=sub("^(\\S+)\\s+.*\\s+(\\S+)$", "\\1 \\2", df1$V1), 
                     header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors= FALSE)
#     V1  V2
#1  fff ddd
#2  sss  dd
#3   de  dd
#4  dds rrr
#5 dsds eed
```

---

Another convenient option is `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
transform(df1, V1 = word(V1, 1), V2 = word(V1, -1))
#   V1  V2
#1  fff ddd
#2  sss  dd
#3   de  dd
#4  dds rrr
#5 dsds eed
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("fff fffd ddd", "sss dd", "de dd",
"dds sssd eew rrr", 
"dsds eed")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```